# Undefined symbols after crashlytics update

Tags: xcode, compilation, linker, crashlytics

I have a problem after update of crashlytics framework in my project, through fabric app of course, it is linker error precisily, log below.

```
Ld /Users/losiennik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InternalApp-cujowfodrnucvoglpkjjfmshsvrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/InternalApp.app/InternalApp normal x86_64
cd /Users/losiennik/temp/InternalApp-ios-fork_DONOTREMOVE
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -L/Users/losiennik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InternalApp-cujowfodrnucvoglpkjjfmshsvrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/losiennik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InternalApp-cujowfodrnucvoglpkjjfmshsvrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/losiennik/temp/InternalApp-ios-fork_DONOTREMOVE -filelist /Users/losiennik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InternalApp-cujowfodrnucvoglpkjjfmshsvrs/Build/Intermediates/InternalApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/InternalApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/InternalApp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lPods-AFNetworking -lPods-ActivateYourSalon -lPods-CocoaLumberjack -lPods-Foursquare-API-v2 -lPods-GZIP -lPods-MBProgressHUD -lPods-MLPAutoCompleteTextField -lPods-MTDates -lPods-UICKeyChainStore -lPods-UIResponder+KeyboardCache -lPods-WYPopoverController -lPods-zipzap -lc++ -lz -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -stdlib=libc++ -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/losiennik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InternalApp-cujowfodrnucvoglpkjjfmshsvrs/Build/Intermediates/InternalApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/InternalApp.build/InternalApp.app.xcent -framework EventKit -framework MessageUI -framework Crashlytics -framework QuartzCore -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods -framework Fabric -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/losiennik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InternalApp-cujowfodrnucvoglpkjjfmshsvrs/Build/Intermediates/InternalApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/InternalApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/InternalApp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/losiennik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InternalApp-cujowfodrnucvoglpkjjfmshsvrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/InternalApp.app/InternalApp

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CLSLog", referenced from:
      -[IAPSyncManager processSuccessfulHTTPRequest] in IAPSyncManager.o
      -[IAPLogService writeContentsOfURL:toStream:] in IAPLogService.o
      -[IAPServerObjectMapping serializedPrimaryKeyToJSONStringFrom:forObject:] in IAPServerObjectMapping.o
  "_CLSNSLog", referenced from:
      ___65-[IAPWeekDashboardViewController asyncInternalAppFetchSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke in IAPWeekDashboardViewController.o
      -[IAPSyncManager prepareForSynchronizationInForeground:] in IAPSyncManager.o
      ___50-[IAPSyncManager reenableIdleTimerAfterTwoMinutes]_block_invoke in IAPSyncManager.o
      -[IAPSyncManager reenableIdleTimer] in IAPSyncManager.o
      -[IAPJSONValidator validateJSONWithError:] in IAPJSONValidator.o
      -[IAPSynchronisationRelationship stringWithID:] in IAPSynchronisationRelationship.o
      _POSTDataDictionary in IAPSyncConstants.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crashlytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IAPSyncManager.o
      objc-class-ref in Crashlytics+Utilities.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_Crashlytics_$_Utilities in Crashlytics+Utilities.o
      objc-class-ref in IAPAppDelegate.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_CrashlyticsPlaceholderStatic)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried to fix that in a lot of manners, but I cannot. Ways that I tried:

- `Xcode Clean` action on the project
- deleting content of `/Users/losiennik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- removing and adding again `Crashlytics.framework` and `Fabric.framework` in `Xcode 6.3.1` target `Build Phases` from `Link Binary from Libraries`
- deleting those framework files from the project physically and adding them again from the other project where I've installed frameworks from the scratch
- deleting `/var/folders` content

I've made every possible combination of that possible solution, and also tried with running and killed xcode, restarting OS also. Nothing works.

Do you have any other ideas? Maybe somebody know where else `Xcode` stores temporary files which can be used while compiling and linking processes? Do somebody have similar experience while updating that framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the cause of the problem was related with the other problem that I had. That problem caused that I couldn't register specific app ID with fabric plugin help which was previously added to our old organization account. I deleted that app ID from that old organization but still couldn't add one to the new organization.

**Thanks to fabric support member**, it turned out that my app ID was in weird state on backend side. When that was corrected, my app ID appeared on our organization account and then the fabric plugin downloaded the proper version of `Crashlytics.framework` file. After that I don't have any problems with `Apple Mach-O Linker Error` related to Crashlytics binaries.

Summarising, when only you have the problem described above or the problem with adding app ID, write directly to fabric support and don't waste your time.

Thanks fabric team :)!

Comment: That doesn't make *any* sense and cannot be the issue.  The state of your app id on some remote server cannot affect the linker in any way.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it also didn't have any sense for me for a few days. But in that specific case, the fabric plugin is responsible for downloading adequate frameworks (Fabric.framework & Crashlytics.framework). While the state of the app ID was wrong, the fabric plugin updated only Fabric.framework without Crashlytics.framework (I also didn't have the newest libraries versions). Then I didn't have proper version of crashlytics binaries, resulting in linker error.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you decided not to use CocoaPods then you obviously used the 2nd option, putting a *Run Script* inside *Build Phases*:

```
./Fabric.framework/run YourUniqueId!#$@#%!#$%@#$^@$3295209582523#@%!#$@%!#%235
```

The run script will copy the files:

- Crashlytics.framework
- Fabric.framework

Into your project directory, but sometimes it is not enough and you also need to copy/reference the 2 frameworks into your Xcode project.

Importing the 2 frameworks is possible (before the above copying procedure) but Xcode needs a reference to them.

Should compile fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This issue came to me when i updated Xcode. It got fixed after uninstalling and installing newer version rather than updating.